# Stuck on Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

We have a query that has been leaving me scratching my head for the past week. The query works on one DB, but not another (apologies for the wall of text):

```
WITH dataset AS
         (  SELECT COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP,
                   TARGET_NAME,
                   METRIC_NAME,
                   KEY_VALUE,
                   KEY_VALUE2,
                   KEY_VALUE3,
                   COLUMN_LABEL,
                   MAX(VALUE) AS VALUE
              FROM (SELECT TO_CHAR(COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP,
                           TARGET_NAME,
                           METRIC_NAME,
                           KEY_VALUE,
                           KEY_VALUE2,
                           KEY_VALUE3,
                           COLUMN_LABEL,
                           VALUE
                      FROM (SELECT MAX(COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP)
                                       OVER(
                                            PARTITION BY TARGET_NAME,
                                                         METRIC_NAME,
                                                         KEY_VALUE,
                                                         KEY_VALUE2,
                                                         KEY_VALUE3,
                                                         COLUMN_LABEL
                                           )
                                       max_my_date,
                                   COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP,
                                   TARGET_NAME,
                                   METRIC_NAME,
                                   KEY_VALUE,
                                   KEY_VALUE2,
                                   KEY_VALUE3,
                                   COLUMN_LABEL,
                                   VALUE
                              FROM MGMT$METRIC_DETAILS
                             WHERE METRIC_LABEL LIKE 'SOX%')
                     WHERE COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP = max_my_date)
             WHERE METRIC_NAME = 'ME$SOXREP_USERS'
          GROUP BY COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP,
                   TARGET_NAME,
                   METRIC_NAME,
                   KEY_VALUE,
                   kEY_VALUE2,
                   KEY_VALUE3,
                   COLUMN_LABEL
          ORDER BY TARGET_NAME ASC,
                   METRIC_NAME ASC,
                   COLUMN_LABEL ASC)
  SELECT (SELECT NVL(amt.AGENT_HOST_NAME, ' ') AS AGENT_HOST_NAME
            FROM MGMT$TARGET t LEFT OUTER JOIN MGMT$AGENTS_MONITORING_TARGETS amt ON t.TARGET_GUID = amt.TARGET_GUID
           WHERE t.TARGET_NAME = prf.TARGET_NAME)
             AS "HOSTNAME",
         (SELECT NVL(PROPERTY_VALUE, ' ')
            FROM MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES
           WHERE     PROPERTY_NAME = 'IP_address'
                 AND TARGET_NAME = (SELECT NVL(amt.AGENT_HOST_NAME, ' ') AS AGENT_HOST_NAME
                                      FROM MGMT$TARGET t LEFT OUTER JOIN MGMT$AGENTS_MONITORING_TARGETS amt ON t.TARGET_GUID = amt.TARGET_GUID
                                     WHERE t.TARGET_NAME = prf.TARGET_NAME))
             AS "IP ADDRESS",
         (SELECT NVL(PROPERTY_VALUE, ' ')
            FROM MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES
           WHERE     PROPERTY_NAME = 'DBVersion'
                 AND TARGET_NAME = prf.TARGET_NAME)
             AS "DB VERSION",
         (SELECT NVL(PROPERTY_VALUE, ' ')
            FROM MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES
           WHERE     PROPERTY_NAME = 'InstanceName'
                 AND TARGET_NAME = prf.TARGET_NAME)
             AS "DB INSTANCE",
         'All database accounts' AS DESCRIPTION,
         prf.KEY_VALUE AS "USERNAME",
         prf.VALUE AS "PROFILE",
         acc.VALUE AS "ACCOUNT STATUS",
         CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(created.VALUE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1') AS DATE) AS "CREATED",
         CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(passwd.VALUE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1') AS DATE) AS "LAST_PWD_CHANGED",
         d.VALUE AS "DAYS_SINCE_LAST_PWD_CHANGED",
         (SELECT NVL(PROPERTY_VALUE, ' ')
            FROM MGMT$TARGET_PROPERTIES
           WHERE     PROPERTY_NAME = 'orcl_gtp_contact'
                 AND TARGET_NAME = prf.TARGET_NAME)
             AS "ENVIRONMENT ROLES",
         CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP(dl.VALUE, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF1') AS DATE) AS "LAST LOGON",
         TO_DATE(prf.COLLECTION_TIMESTAMP, 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') AS "COLLECTION DATE"
    FROM dataset prf,
         dataset acc,
         dataset created,
         dataset passwd,
         dataset d,
         dataset dl
   WHERE     prf.TARGET_NAME = acc.TARGET_NAME
         AND prf.KEY_VALUE = acc.KEY_VALUE
         AND prf.TARGET_NAME = created.TARGET_NAME
         AND prf.KEY_VALUE = created.KEY_VALUE
         AND prf.TARGET_NAME = passwd.TARGET_NAME
         AND prf.KEY_VALUE = passwd.KEY_VALUE
         AND prf.TARGET_NAME = d.TARGET_NAME
         AND prf.KEY_VALUE = d.KEY_VALUE
         AND prf.TARGET_NAME = dl.TARGET_NAME
         AND prf.KEY_VALUE = dl.KEY_VALUE
         AND prf.COLUMN_LABEL = 'PROFILE'
         AND acc.COLUMN_LABEL = 'ACCOUNT STATUS'
         AND created.COLUMN_LABEL = 'CREATED'
         AND passwd.COLUMN_LABEL = 'LAST PWD CHANGE'
         AND d.COLUMN_LABEL = 'Days since last pwd change'
         AND dl.COLUMN_LABEL = 'LAST LOGON'
ORDER BY 1 ASC,
         4,
         5 DESC
```

On one DB, the query runs just fine. On the other DB though, we get the following:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

I've been trying to deconstruct the query in an attempt to figure out which portion of the query is causing the issue, but so far I've had no luck. I understand that a subquery which is supposed to return only one row is returning 2 or more, but I'm struggling to figure out which one it is.

My question: Is there an easier way for me to figure out which portion of the SQL query is causing the issue instead of having to try to deconstruct the query and running it bit by bit?

Comment: Try to wrap every subquery, except the one you use for the =, within a select count(1) from (yourSubquery). If you still have the error, the issue is in the subquery used for the = check, otherwise, you only have to check which one gives more a result greater than 1.

Comment: Do a LEFT JOIN instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your subqueries to check which one gives more than one row, at least for the queries you don't need to check against a value. For example:

```
SQL> select
  2      (select 1 from dual) as result_1,
  3      (select 1 from dual connect by level < 10) as result_2
  4  from dual;
    (select 1 from dual connect by level < 10) as result_2
              *
ERROR at line 3:
ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row


SQL> select
  2      (select count(1) from (select 1 from dual)) as check1,
  3      (select count(1) from (select 1 from dual connect by level < 10)) as check_2
  4  from dual;

    CHECK1    CHECK_2
---------- ----------
         1          9
```

Here you know that the issue is in the second query.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far Aleksej, giving it a go now.

Comment: Aleksej, accepting your recommendation as the answer. I ended up inserting a count (*) into each and every single subquery, though it didn't end up giving me a count or line number that failed, but this did allow me to comment out each subquery until the query as a whole returned data. From there, I edited the subquery in question and added a "WHERE ROWNUM = 1" clause and presto, it finally worked. Thanks again for helping me out, much appreciated.